# Check for a string in a folder with an if statement

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I m looking to do an action when a bahsscript find a string in files on my home but somehow it's does not work and I don't understand why..
I have the impression that my grep does not return 0 (whereas the string is really present in a file).

```
#!/bin/bash 
find /home/ -type f | xargs grep -q 'stringtofind' 
 if [ $? == 0 ] #if the result is not equal to zero 
 then 
  echo "Action" 
 else 
  echo "Pas d'action" 
  exit 1 
 fi 
exit 0
```

When I'm doing the following my shell returns me 123 instead of 0

```
find /home/anselmewebsite/ -type f | xargs grep -q 'stringtofind' ; echo $?
shell returns : 123
```

Thanks in advance for your highlights,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-r` option of grep to make it grep in a folder recursively:

```
grep -r yourstring /path/to/your/folder
```

From the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep):

> -R, -r, --recursive
>
> Read all files under each directory, recursively; this is equivalent to the -d recurse option.

Comment: thank you very much..As I said before I have no idea why I used xargs when grep can do it by itself.. beginners fault. thanks again.

Comment: @Anselme no problem. Note that some distributions provide a `rgrep` shorthand for `grep -r`. If your distribution does not, you can create an alias in your .bashrc: `alias rgrep="grep -r"`

Comment: thanks for the useful tips.. Indeed grep -r will be needed a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a return Code of xargs, if you look into the manual you find:

> 123 if any invocation of the command exited with status 1-125

This means that your grep returned with an non-zero exit code, which is the case when grep doesn´t match the string:

> Normally,  the  exit  status is 0 if selected lines are found and 1 otherwise.

So I would strongly suggest that you use grep with the -R recursive Option, this should return 0 if there is a match in any of the files. In the example above as soon as you ahve one file which doesn´t contain your search pattern, xargs will return 123 and the logic of your script breaks.

Comment: thank you very much.. You are right. I have no idea why I used xargs when grep can do it by itself.. beginners fault. thanks again.

Comment: @Anselme, not a "fault", you're learning. This was a good question.